# I have 3 activity page,while selecting spinner item correponding activitypage will selected and displayed.Hw can i implement.?

Tags: android-intent, spinner, android-spinner

here is my code.In my spinner i have 3 items.each items hav seperate activity  pages.while i select the item corresponding activity displayed,all the activity page layout and spinner are same.spinner and text view are in all activites.suppose i select second activity from spinner and i go second, there also one spinner,and if i select third activity from that spinner it goes to that page.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.car);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.vehicles_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, bus.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("str",arg0.getSelectedItem().toString());
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });


   and here is my xml code.



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/silver"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/inner_wrapper">
          <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/Level_0"> 
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:prompt="@string/select">
                <requestFocus />
            </Spinner>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/Audi">
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="@string/AUDI_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@color/lightred"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/BMW">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="@string/BMW_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/lightgreen"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/Indigo"> 
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="@string/INDIGO_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String txt = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(txt.equals("page1")){
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity1.class));}

        else if(txt.equals("page2")){
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity2.class));}

        else if(txt.equals("page3")){
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity3.class));}

        else if(txt.equals("page4")){
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity4.class));}

        else {
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity5.class));}
    }
});
```

And you must add your Activities in `Android Manifest` file

Comment: I guess did you use same string for condition ie) "page1" use your vehicle_name string for condition :)

Comment: And also put your array string data which is containing in Spinner